# asp.net bootstrap start project

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know a good, complete, simple asp.net project that implements Twitter bootstrap.

I want to create a website that uses ASP.net and is responsive and uses bootstrap. That involves probably a lot of libraries and links to jquery, etcetera. The first time it is a lot of investigation and somebody must have done this before and might be willing to give me a head start.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net Web Forms Template and MVC Template come with Twitter Bootstrap already.

Once you select Web Forms Template or MVC Template *(Screen Shot 2)*, it'll download all required styles,  scripts and fonts via NuGet

[image]

[image]